# unable to download app ios 7.1.2

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning, adhoc

i have developed an app but i face issue when i make a build for adhoc, it successfully run on my own device with iOS 7.0.1 every time but when i want to run on iOS 7.1.2 it give prompt message "unable to download app" i have tried very much, but unable to solve this issue till yet.I have implemented bar code scan in this app, I have developed on both development and distribution provisioning profiles. i have correct UDIDs and everything is ok. What should i do?  Any suggestion, Please help. I usually upload ipa file to diawi.com

Comment: What did you set the target iOS version to? If it's set to 7.0 instead of 7.1, it might throw that error.

Comment: Set it to 7.1 and see what happens.

Comment: No, it won't. But does it run on your 7.1.2 device?

Comment: Mobione tools for build ios app..

Answer (score 1):

- Edit adhoc Provisional Profile or create new Provisional Profile.
- Select all devices that you have in apple account.
- Download certificate and double click to install.
- Create new .ipa file to install.

  Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be about the provision profile. I had a similar problem but then i recognized i didn't download provision file again after i added UDID of the phone. So the provision file I was using wasn't containing this new phone UDID. After downloading provision file again i replaced the old one with the new one, then problem solved.